# Inteiro com 0 à esquerda é impresso como outro número

Tags: php, inteiros

Eu tenho este código:

```
$mob_numbers= array(02345674, 12345675, 22345676, 32345677);
echo ($mob_numbers[0]);
```

Queria imprimir o primeiro elemento do `array` mas o *output* disso é:

> 641980

Porque é que isso acontece?

Comment: Leitura complementar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25031/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Números iniciados com zero, desde que válidos, são interpretados com base 8 (octal), ou seja, `02345674` foi interpretado com base 8 e sua representação em base 10 é `641980`.

O manual alerta sobre isso na página sobre [integers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

Esse [site](http://www.statman.info/conversions/octal.html) faz conversões entre base 8 X base 10

Comment: @Miguel Basta tirar o zero do começo.

Answer (score 11):

Como dito pelo @perdeu O [**manual do php**](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.integer.php) menciona este comportamento

> $a = 0123; // número octal (equivalente a 83 em decimal)

Sendo assim a melhor forma de se imprimir o valor de inteiros que tenham um 0 à esquerda é:

```
$mob_numbers = array("02345674", "12345675", "22345676", "32345677");
echo (int)$mob_numbers[0];    //Retorno 2345674
```

`(int)` converte a string para inteiro, isso garante que o número se mantenha como inteiro, como você pode ver no artigo [**Conversão de tipos de dados no PHP**](http://aprenderphp.com.br/artigo/conversao-de-tipos-de-dados-no-php/).

Comment: Muito obgado, entendi

Answer (score 5):

Você poderá obter o mesmo resultado, sem converter os valores do seu `array` para `string`, se utilizar a função `sprintf`
para gravar o valor formatado que deseja obter.

No caso, a opção `'%o'` da função faz com que "O argumento seja tratado como um inteiro, e mostrado como um número octal" (Trecho tirado do Manual do PHP).

Se você quer obter os zeros, terá que utilizar `'%08o'`. Isso retornará o valor preenchido com zeros a esquerda caso haja menos que `8` números no seu inteiro.

Exemplo:

```
    $mob_numbers= array(02345674, 12345675, 22345676, 32345677);

    echo sprintf('%08o', $mob_numbers[0]); // preenche com zero quando não há 8 números

    echo sprintf('%o', $mob_numbers[0]); // formata o valor sem o zero
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode trabalhar com esses números como `string`.

Basta adicionar aspas:

```
$mob_numbers= array("02345674", "12345675", "22345676", "32345677");
echo ($mob_numbers[0]);
```