# O que significa o "0x" no início dos números hexadecimais?

Tags: hexadecimal

Percebi que quando se trata de números hexadecimais às vezes é colocado um `0x` na frente.

Por exemplo, `0xA1B2C3` ao invés de `A1B2C3`.

O que esse `0x` significa?

Comment: As linguagens usam o prefixo `0x` como forma de diferenciar valores hexadecimais de outros valores (`int`, `string`, etc).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Já foi respondido pelo [Lucas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25033/70) que "o prefixo 0x identifica o numero que segue como uma constante hexadecimal", mas quero complementar a resposta com alguns detalhes relevantes:

> **P:** Para que usar um prefixo?
>   **R:** Para diferenciar de um decimal, pois é perfeitamente normal um hexa sem letra nenhuma. `0x99`, por exemplo, é `153` em decimal, mas se você escrevesse `int x = 99`, o compilador não teria como adivinhar a sua intenção. o `0x99` já deixa explícito que é hexa.

Curiosidades:

Esta é uma verdadeira pegadinha do malandro: em algumas linguagens, o `0` (sem o `x`) antes de números, indica "octal", assim, `x = 032` é a mesma coisa que `x = 26`. Isso sim confunde com facilidade quem não tem experiência com prefixos.

Já vi certos dialetos BASIC usando `&b` ou `0b` para indicar binário, por exemplo `0b00001011` para representar o decimal `11`, assim como em alguns casos o `&h` para hexadecimal (no [MSX](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Msx), `&h8000` é o modo usual de se representar o início da memória disponível para escrita depois de um boot normal).

Uma das linguagens que eu uso bastante (Harbour), usa `0d` pra datas. Por exemplo, `dNascimento := 0d20010527`.

Comment: Existe alguma lista com todos os prefixos, ou são apenas estes?

Comment: @Patrick os mais comuns são o `0x` pra hexadecimal e apenas `0` para octal, mas é uma característica individual das linguagens, e não um padrão. Vale a pena consultar a documentação específica da linguagem mesmo.

Comment: Algumas linguagens se deram conta que o 0 para octal não era uma boa ideia (demoraram, hein?) e estão em processo de transição para remover esse prefixo ou trocá-lo por 0o (com a letra "o" de "octal"). Por exemplo: JavaScript, Python, Scala, D.

Comment: @marcus (meio atrasado) Não entendi o problema de usar 0 para octal.

Comment: @Piovezan O primeiro motivo está na resposta: 032 (oct) vale 26 (dec). Vai dizer que não é confuso que só um zero na frente muda todo o valor do número? Não é assim que devia ser... E se você estiver trabalhando com meses (de 1 a 12) e quiser colocar um 0 frente pra alinhar, vai dar erro em 08 e 09 (números octais inválidos). Isso sem falar na assimetria: porque hexadecimal usa o 0x e octal é só o 0? Deve ser da época quando octal era mais utilizado que hexadecimal.

Answer (score 22):

`0x` ou `0X` é um prefixo que foi inicialmente utilizado por compiladores assembly da AT&T no final da década de 1960 para representar valores numéricos hexadecimais.

[Bell Laboratories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Labs), na época uma subsidiária da AT&T, foi a primeira a adotar o padrão. Ela é também conhecida por criar o ambiente operacional [UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix), onde fez largo uso dessa notação. Vários descendentes sintáticos do *NIX (C, C#, Java, JavaScript e outros) propagaram o uso até os dias atuais.

O `0` (zero) inicial indica que o valor é uma constante numérica; `x` é foneticamente parecido, em inglês, com 'Hexa'.

Comment: +1 por incluir uma aula de história na resposta :)

Comment: @Renan Obrigado! Achei relevante, e é sempre interessante aprender um pouco mais sobre o que se gosta =)

Answer (score 8):

O prefixo `0x` identifica o numero que segue como uma constante hexadecimal, e o prefixo `0` como um numero em octal (base 8).

Por exemplo,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << 0xF << endl;
    cout << 010 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Vai imprimir 15 e 8 na tela.

Answer (score 6):

Algumas linguaguens definem `0x` como prefixo de um número hexadecimal, basicamente é uma sinalização para o compilador/interpretador de que o número deve ser tratado em outra base(16).

[php inteiros](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.integer.php)