# Qual a diferença do Integer.valueOf() ao usar parâmetros String ou int?

Tags: java, string, int

Por que nas linhas abaixo os resultados do `System.out` são diferentes?

```
Integer teste = Integer.valueOf("0422");
Resultado: 422

Integer teste = Integer.valueOf(0422);
Resultado: 274
```

Se passo um `int` ele muda o valor original, agora se passo uma `String` ele mantém o valor.

```
long teste1 = 0422;
Resultado: 274

int teste2 = 0422;
Resultado: 274
```

Comment: Relacionado:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25031/7261

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Quando você faz `Integer.valueOf(0422)`, graças ao prefixo `0` no começo do número, a conversão será feita baseando-se que o valor esta na  na base octal, e não na base decimal. Que é diferente de você fazer `Integer.valueOf(422)`, que como não tem o prefixo `0` quer dizer que o número 422 está em decimal mesmo.

Os possíveis prefixos para mudar de base são:

> 0b - indica que o número é um binário
>   0  - indica que o número é um octal
>   0x - indica que o número é um hexadecimal

Quando você manda imprimir com o `System.out.println()`, o resultado é impresso sempre em decimal, e como 422 em octal é igual a 274 em decimal o valor impresso é 274.

Exemplo:

```
public class BaseNumerica {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("422 em octal == " + Integer.valueOf(0422) + " em decimal");
        System.out.println("422 em decimal: " + Integer.valueOf(422));
        System.out.println("422 de String para inteiro decimal: " + Integer.valueOf("0422"));
        //Comprovando que 274 em decimal vale 422 em octal 
        System.out.printf("Decimal: %d ; Octal: %o", 274, 274);
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> 422 em octal == 274 em decimal
>   422 em decimal: 422
>   422 de String para inteiro decimal: 422
>   Decimal: 274 ; Octal: 422

Diferentemente do `Integer.valueOf(int i)`, o método `Integer.valueOf(String s)` não leva em consideração o prefixo para mudar a base do número lido. A forma correta para mudar a base do número que será lido a partir da String é usando o método `valueOf(String s, int radix)`, e indicando a base no segundo parâmetro do método. Exemplo:

```
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf("422", 8));
```

Ele entende que o valor de 422 está em octal, e em seguida imprime o valor 274 em decimal.

Veja a documentação: [Integer - Java SE7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String,%20int))