# Palavra chave "new" no C#

Tags: c#, classes, objetos, instanciar-objeto

Fui ver sobre a palavra chave `new` no C#, mas não achei alguém que explique bem o que eu quero saber. Dizem que o `new` cria uma nova instância, mas não entendi exatamente o que querem dizer com "criar uma instância".

Comment: Olá @Gatti, veja essa documentação oficial do C#, vai te ajudar.
[Documentação palavra chave new c#](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/instance-constructors) caso considere como resposta, favor marcar ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grosso modo podemos dizer que uma instância é um objeto. No caso estamos dizendo que está criando um objeto de um tipo específico.

Quando escrevemos o código criamos duas coisas, uma estrutura de dados e algoritmos que operam essas estruturas. Em linguagens que adotam a orientação a objeto é comum que essas duas coisas sejam escritas juntas formando um tipo. Esse tipo pode ser uma classe, mas não precisa sempre assim, tem outras formas de organizar os dados e os algoritmos que forma um tipo.

[Sempre que queremos criar um objeto usamos um modelo de como este objeto é criado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101).

Quando queremos criar um objeto nós dizemos de qual tipo será este objeto, então chamamos o construtor do tipo (um deles, porque pode ter mais de um), mas até para não confundir com uma chamada de método normal e também para deixar claro que haverá uma alocação na memória naquele ponto também usamos o operador de `new` antes do nome do construtor.

[Não confundir com outro `new` existente na linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151246/101).

Pode lhe interessar: [Diferença entre "Atributo" e "Variável de Instância"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96710/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então por exemplo: Eu tenho isso: public class Exemplo { private Exemplo ex = new Exemplo() }                                 Quer dizer que eu criei um novo endereço na memória para essa nova instância classe ex com os novos valores do construtor(no caso não coloquei nenhum valor então ele invoca o construtor padrão).  É isso?

Comment: É basicamente isto, embora a forma correta seja um pouco diferente, precisaria entender outros conceitos anteriores para poder entender esses mais avançados de forma mais precisa.

Comment: Obrigado! Ajudou MUITO!

Comment: Só mais uma coisa... resolvi complementar o que eu acho que é o New... por exemplo... public class Exemplo { int A = 2 Exemplo (int a) { int a = A} private Exemplo Ex = new Exemplo() } Eu criei um novo endereço na memória para a classe Exemplo, e como a instância Ex é do tipo Exemplo ela pode ser armazenada no mesmo local da memória que Exemplo... com os valores novos do construtor... mas herdando tudo da classe Exemplo, pois estão no mesmo local na memória... agora está correto? Está faltando alguma coisa?

Comment: `new` não cria endereços de memória, endereços existem por si só. Você não leu minha resposta com atenção. Eu disse que ele cria um objeto, não endereço. Como dois corpos podem ocupar o mesmo lugar no espaço? Não falamos nada de herança, `new` nada tem a ver com isso, isto não faz parte do escopo do que estamos falando. Todos seus conceitos estão errados. Talvez fosse o caso de fazer outra pergunta com todos esses detalhes, e reforço a ideia de detalhar muito tudo, se possível por exemplos, apresentar todo seu entendimento, e todas as dúvidas

Comment: Desde que relacionadas, senão tem que ser perguntas separadas. Esta pergunta precisa ser muito bem feita para ser aceita no site. Também reforço que está faltando entendimento básico antes de saber sobre o `new`.

Comment: Então acho que todos os meus conceitos sobre o próprio C# estão errados... ou pelo menos nessa área de instâncias... acho que vou criar uma nova pegunta...

Comment: @Gatti mas para esse problema a resposta já está ok? Veja o [tour] o que você pode fazer. Pode aceitar a resposta e votar nela também. Voto você pode dar em tudo no site.

Comment: Ok... voltei. Etendendo um pouco mais... na verdade eu já terminei vários cursos online, fazem 6 meses que vejo sobre programação, e sei usar o C# muito bem... o problema é que em nenhum desses cursos definem "instância" ou o "New" você acaba usando eles sem saber direito o que fazem...e por isso sobraram alguns "buracos" no meu entendimento sobre o C#. E apesar da sua resposta ser muito boa, eu ainda não consigo entender direito o que o "New" faz... eu tenho uma base bem sólida no C#, por exemplo eu sei usar o "New", mas não sei o que ele faz no sistema... espero que tenha dado para entender.

Comment: Já te falei que não é assim que o site funciona e vou te mandar só mais uma coisa pra te ajudar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect

Answer (score 2):

Antes de entender o conceito do operador `new` é necessário entender bem o que é uma *variável*.
Depois é necessário entender o conceito básico de *estruturas* e *classes*.

---

Em termos gerais, uma **variável** é o mecanismo na programação para se armazenar (e acessar) em memória algum valor que será usado novamente em algum ponto do programa.

Exemplos de variáveis de "tipos simples" *(leia nota no final da resposta)*:

```
int   i = 123;
float f = 1.23F;
bool  b = true;
char  c = 'X';
```

O código acima definiu quatro variáveis, `i`, `f`, `b` e `c`. Elas são **variáveis** porque  o valor que elas armazenam pode variar, pode ser alterado, ao longo de suas [*vidas*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/86952). Já os valores atribuídos a elas, `123`, `1.23F`, `true` e `'X'`, são **constantes**, porque `123` será sempre `123`, não é possível alterá-lo.

Como eu disse, uma variável armazena um valor na **memória**, então, quando você define uma variável como `int i;`, o que acontece nos bastidores é que o computador verifica qual endereço na memória está disponível para armazenar um tipo `int`, por exemplo *0x12345000* (notação para um número [hexadecimal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25031/86952)), e atribui esse endereço à variável `i`. Como o tipo `int` ocupa 4 bytes, nesse momento a faixa de endereço na memória do seu programa de *0x12345000* a *0x12345003* estará reservada à sua variável `i`. Quando você atribuir algum valor à essa variável, o programa armazenará esse valor nesse endereço da memória, e quando você consultar o valor dessa variável, o programa irá buscar o valor armazenado nesse endereço da memória.

Esses exemplos que citei são "tipos simples", mas existem também tipos mais complexos, como estruturas e classes.

---

Basicamente, uma **estrutura** é um agrupamento de variáveis, que servem a um mesmo propósito.

Exemplo de definição de uma estrutura:

```
public struct Point
{
   public int X;
   public int Y;
}
```

E uma **classe** também é, de certa forma, um agrupamento de variáveis que servem a um mesmo propósito (quando essas variáveis são internas chamamos de *campos*, quando podem ser acessadas de fora da classe chamamos de *propriedades*, a grosso modo), mas também um agrupamento de funções que servem a esse propósito (chamadas de *métodos*). No C# uma estrutura também pode ter propriedades e métodos, mas [existem diferenças entre uma e outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/86952).

Exemplo de definição de uma classe:

```
public class MinhaClasse
{
   private int meuCampo;

   public int MinhaPropriedade
   {
      get { return this.meuCampo; }
      set { this.meuCampo = value; }
   }

   public int MeuMetodo()
   {
      return this.meuCampo * 2;
   } 
}
```

Mas mesmo quando usamos esses tipos mais complexos, o mesmo conceito de variável continua valendo: a variável é um nome dado a um endereço da memória que está armazenando nossos valores (no caso de classes a variável na verdade armazena uma [**referência**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) para outro endereço na memória, que contém os nossos valores, de fato, mas, vamos manter a ideia simples).

A definição de uma estrutura ou classe não contém valores variáveis (mas pode conter valores constantes), porque é apenas um modelo, uma "casca vazia sem conteúdo". Quando queremos usar esse modelo (estrutura ou classe) criamos um **objeto**, que [*é uma instância de um tipo de objeto*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/192573/86952) (tipo de objeto = estrutura ou classe). Aí estamos atribuindo "conteúdo à casca vazia".

A nossa variável nesse caso será então o nosso meio de acesso ao endereço da memória em que está armazenado o nosso objeto (ou a referência ao nosso objeto). Como qualquer outra variável, ao longo de sua vida ela pode receber outros valores, ou seja, outros objetos. Então:

```
// Atribui à minha variável um objeto que já existe.
MinhaClasse meuObjeto = outroObjetoDoMesmoTipo;
```

---

## Finalmente respondendo à pergunta:

Mas, quando queremos criar um **novo objeto**, um que ainda não existe, devemos usar o operador `new`:

```
// Cria um novo objeto e atribui à minha variável.
MinhaClasse meuNovoObjeto = new MinhaClasse();
```

Esse novo objeto provavelmente virá com os valores todos zerados (ou com seus valores constantes padrão, que podem ser diferentes de zero), a não ser que nosso tipo (estrutura ou classe) tenha um [**construtor**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/86952) que inicialize nosso novo objeto com valores informados na hora de sua criação, com o operador `new`.

---

**Nota sobre "tipos simples"**
No começo da resposta eu citei os tipos `int`, `float`, `bool` e `char` como tipos simples, e eles realmente são considerados assim ([documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables)), tanto que não precisam do operador `new` para que se crie um novo objeto desses tipos, mas, no C# mesmo esses tipos simples são, no fundo, estruturas.