# Zero a esquerda dentro de variável inteira

Tags: php, int

Boa tarde pessoal, bateu a seguinte duvida:

Quando defino dentro de uma variável inteira o zero a esquerda ela me retorna no echo uma numero nada a ver, gostaria de saber porque:

Segue exemplificação:

```
 <?php
 echo $inteiro = 015;
//me retorna o seguinte valor: 13 gostaria de saber o pq?
 ?>
```

Comment: Um zero a esquerda sinaliza para o php que esse número deve ser interpretado em base 8(octal). [Inteiro com 0 à esquerda é impresso como outro número](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9299/91)

Comment: Leitura complementar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25031/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Porque a 015 é a representação octogonal do decimal 13.

copiado do manual

```
<?php
$a = 1234; // decimal number
$a = -123; // a negative number
$a = 0123; // octal number (equivalent to 83 decimal)
$a = 0x1A; // hexadecimal number (equivalent to 26 decimal)
$a = 0b11111111; // binary number (equivalent to 255 decimal)
?>
```

Comment: resposta perfeita

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Manuel

Comment: Engraçado que mesmo forçando o tipo: `$int = (int) 015;` o PHP ainda identifica o resultado como octogonal e altera o valor da variável.

Comment: @Kazzkiq independente da notação ele continua sendo um inteiro. A notação é apenas um forma diferente de escrever um numero ou um caractere. Mal comparando é como escrever em português ou inglês, o numero continua sendo o mesmo.