# Como converter número em bilhões para uma cadeia menor de comparação?

Tags: php, lógica

Imagine que tenha um exercício no seguinte aspecto, preciso pegar de um array com inteiros aleatórios, o maior número que está entre os intervalos.

Por exemplo, tenho um array: `array(2, 8, 4);`

1. teria que ordenar: 2,4,8
2. verificar o intervalo de 2 a 4 = 2, e de 4 a 8 = 4
3. o maior intervalo, neste caso, seria o **4**, entre 4 e 8.

Partindo dessa ideia, eu tenho a seguinte estrutura de código:

```
<?php

class VerifyNumbers
{

    private $arr = array();

    public function __construct(array $arr)
    {
        $this->arr = $arr;
    }

    public function verifyMaxIntersectionFromArray()
    {
        $collection = array();

         sort($this->arr);

        for ($i= 0; $i < count($this->arr); $i++) {
            if (isset($this->arr[$i + 1])) {
               $collection[] = ($this->arr[$i + 1] - $this->arr[$i]);
            }
        } 
        return max($collection);
    }

}

$verifyNumber = new VerifyNumbers(array(100, 3000, 4000, 25, 540, 20, 200, 300));
$maxIntersection = $verifyNumber->verifyMaxIntersectionFromArray();

echo $maxIntersection;
```

A pergunta que eu faço é, e se no caso, eu tivesse valores de entrada neste array que ultrapassassem a casa de 4 bilhões, ou até maiores, pois poderia haver números negativos, o que dobraria, o intervalo, como eu poderia converter estes números de entrada em uma cadeia menor e legível, pois no PHP 5, um dígito inválido é passado para inteiro octal (por exemplo, 8 ou 9), o resto do número será ignorado.

Comment: Talvez isto ajude Ivan: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9299/inteiro-com-0-%C3%A0-esquerda-%C3%A9-impresso-como-outro-n%C3%BAmero

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Comment: Será que seu PHP é de 32 bits e está estourando o limite máximo dos números?

Comment: Achei a sua descrição um pouco confusa.
"o *maior* número que está entre os intervalos. "? 
De 2 a 4 = 2 ( 2 é menor que 4 e não maior, então vc se refere a 4-2? Ou quer o menor deles ao invés do maior?)
4 a 8 = 4 (mesma coisa do questionamento anterior)

Comment: sim, me refiro a subtração.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve formatar o número. Imaginemos que `$num` é a variável do número que eu quero formatar:

```
echo "O seu número formatado é: ". number_format($num, 4);
```

O que está na frente do `$num` é quantas casas este número vai ter. Então, nesse caso, em vez de ser por exemplo 1,000000 vai ser 1,0000!